# Capture the result of Spring method invocation using XML

Tags: spring

I have two beans: a bean referenced by a variable `end` and another bean referenced by `propertyObject`. The bean referenced by `end` contains a method `addProperty` which takes a string and an object of the type of which the object referenced by `propertyObject` is an instance. In other words, you can pass a string and `propertyObject` to `addProperty`. In Java code, the invocation will look like the following:

```
end.addProperty("propertyObject", propertyObject);
```

In Spring XML, the code will look like the following:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="end"/>
    <property name="targetMethod" value="addProperty"/>
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <value>"property"</value>
            <ref bean="propertyObject" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The method `addProperty` returns an object and I want to capture it as a Spring bean.

In Java code, you will write

```
Object obj = end.addProperty("propertyObject", propertyObject);
```

but I want to know how to do this using Spring XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a factory method and pass the arguments as constructor arguments.

```
<bean id="end" class="Yourclass">
</bean>

<bean id="obj" factory-bean="end" factory-method="addProperty">
    <constructor-arg value="propertyObject" />
    <constructor-arg ref="propertyObject" />
</bean>
```

Should do the trick. However you might want to consider using java based configuration as that will make things a whole lot easier .

Comment: I prefer the idea of Java based configuration but the only problem is that I have no access to or edit the source code of the library that contains multiple examples of the scenario I described. Thanks anyway for helping me. You've helped me avoid a big headache in my current project.